# Crear un Map a partir de otro Map en dart o flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, map

Buen día.

Consulta, tengo un

```
lista = {"A" : 100, "B" : 80, "C": 70, "D": 60, "E": 50, "F": 30}
```

Lo que deseo es obtener un `Map` con los 3 primeros elementos:

```
listaFinal = {"A" : 100, "B" : 80, "C": 70}
```

¿Solo puedo crear mi `listaFinal`  haciéndole un `for` o existe otra manera de obtener el `listaFinal` ?

Adicionalmente existirá alguna forma de sumar sus elementos sin hacer un `for` que recorra elemento `x` elemento.

Osea, obtener algo así

```
MapFinal2 = {"A" : 100, "B" : 80, "C": 70, "OTROS": 140}
```

Donde "OTROS" tiene la suma de "E", "F" y "G"

Este codigo estoy usando para sumar:

```
var sum = lista.entries
  //.where((e) => e.key.startsWith('A'))
  .map<int>((e) => e.value)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

Pero en el Where no se que poner para que solo me sume los 3 o 4 primeros elementos del Map. Adicionalmente quisiera cortar mi Primer mapa y obtener solo los 3 primeros.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código que tenes actualmente?

Comment: Podrías usar for sin problemas, ya que es un recorrido lineal de complejidad o(n),  es lo mismo a que uses map, o reduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para el primer caso:

```dart
    final map = {"A": 100, "B": 80, "C": 70, "D": 60, "E": 50, "F": 30}
      ..removeWhere((key, value) => key.compareTo("C") > 0);
    print(map);
```

Para el segundo caso, como mencioné, un simple for tiene complejidad O(n), por lo que no afecta nada.

```dart
    final map2 = {"A": 100, "B": 80, "C": 70, "D": 60, "E": 50, "F": 30};

    int sum = 0;
    for (String key in Map.from(map2).keys) {
      if (key.compareTo("C") > 0) {
        sum += map2[key];
        map2.remove(key);
      }
    }
    map2["OTROS"] = sum;
    print(map2);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda en caso que no sepa que el nombre del key sea al azar es decir sea en vez de 'C' sea otra letra como podria hacer el compare, quiza jugar con la posicion. La data me viene ordenada.

Comment: Modifique tu codigo de esta manera para obtener lo que necesito si hubiese otra forma me gustaria saberlo. Muchas Gracias por la ayuda.                       
 final map2 = {"A": 100, "B": 80, "C": 70, "D": 60, "E": 50, "F": 30};

    int sum = 0;
    int cant = 1;
    for (String key in Map.from(map2).keys) {
      //if (key.compareTo("C") > 0) {
      cant ++;
      if (cant > 4) {
        sum += map2[key];
        map2.remove(key);
      }
    }
    map2["OTROS"] = sum;
    print(map2);

Comment: ok, está bien si lo manejas así, el reducer te sirve para listas, tendrías que hacer varias conversiones con tu map, por eso creo que un for es lo más adecuado en este caso.